# Rkhunter warnings help

Tags: rkhunter

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 a few days ago. I've made a scan with a RkHunter and got a few warnings that I don't really know what to do with. I read about false positives a little bit but I didn't find the answer for myself really. I got those errors:

```
Checking /dev for suspicious file types         [ Warning ]
[19:44:16] Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
[19:44:16]          /dev/.udev/rules.d/root.rules: ASCII text
[19:44:16]   Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
[19:44:16] Warning: Hidden directory found: /etc/.java: directory
[19:44:16] Warning: Hidden directory found: /dev/.udev: directory
[19:44:16] Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.initramfs: symbolic link to `/run/initramfs'
Checking for group file changes                 [ Warning ]
[19:44:16] Warning: Group 'winbindd_priv' has been added to the group file.
```

Should I be worried ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok lets run this down:

> [19:44:16]          /dev/.udev/rules.d/root.rules: ASCII text

- a file holding ASCII text is suspicious? Why?
- there was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/591807) in it in 2010 so the file seems normal to me.
- google says [false positive](https://www.google.nl/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%2Fdev%2F.udev%2Frules.d%2Froot.rules&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZA3mV--THpTc8Afm56Bg).

> [19:44:16] Warning: Hidden directory found: /etc/.java: directory
>
> [19:44:16] Warning: Hidden directory found: /dev/.udev: directory
>
> [19:44:16] Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.initramfs: symbolic link to `/run/initramfs'

- hidden files are a problem? Why? Hidden file to me seem a -feature- of linux.
- [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rkhunter/+bug/219840) and [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rkhunter/+bug/219840/comments/10).
- The "fix" also shows a serious flaw in rkhunter: putting files into a configuration file so it skips them is just plain stupid. It really is. Think about what this means: so if I add -all- files on my disk to the configuration file so it skips them I can never get a rootkit? No, it actually means a rootkit has extra places to hide itself. Seems counterproductive to me.

> [19:44:16] Warning: Group 'winbindd_priv' has been added to the group file.

- [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/64425) and [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/64425/comments/8). Fix is part of correctly setting up winbindd.

---

By the way: you are the one choosing to use rkunter so you will also need to do these searches yourself on any warning you get.

Either don't use rkhunter or install a -second- separate (so not [Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) as it is a rkhunter clone) ([chrootkit.org](http://www.chkrootkit.org/) seems down; software is still available in the repositories). Run both and discard anything only 1 of them reports as a problem as a false positive. [Package information on debian for rkhunter also mentions this](https://packages.debian.org/sid/admin/rkhunter).

Comment: Hi, updating for "new 2018's sample list", see appended list at question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't be worried about false positives.

How to install, configure and use RKhunter is explained in the [RKhunter community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter). Also there you can find detailed explanations about some expected results like yours and how to properly whitelist them.

Comment: Hi, updating for "new 2018's sample list", see appended list at question.