# rkhunter warnings on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: rkhunter

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and have recently installed and run rkhunter 1.4.4. I got the following warnings about ***suspicious shared memory segments***:

```
/usr/lib/nautilus-desktop PID 1867
```

Is this a problem? Could there be a problem with rkhunter not playing well with the newest Ubuntu? Can I safely ignore this, especially if I don't get a warning when I am not running Firefox at the same time, and I do get a warning if Firefox is running?

Comment: You have to investigate those warnings, like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/828811/rkhunter-warnings-help . People will tell you rkhunter and clamav (and similar) are notorious for "false positives" These are not false positives, it is a grey zone. These programs can not guarantee these files are safe and thus you have to investigate. If you are not going to investigate, why run these tools at all ?

Comment: See my comments here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/988729/clamtk-reports-these-libreoffice-files-as-possible-threats-are-they-safe/988826#988826

Comment: some explanation about "suspicious shared memory segments": https://serverfault.com/questions/697865/rkhunter-suspicious-shared-memory-segments